# Docker exec environment different to container shell

Tags: docker, bash

I have a docker image that looks something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install packages for building ruby
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install build-essential git curl wget net-tools apt-utils sudo man \
libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev nano gcc rubygems ruby-dev

# Install rbenv and ruby-build
ENV PATH /root/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git /root/.rbenv && \
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git /root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build && \
/root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/install.sh && \
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> /etc/profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.profile && \
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc

# Install ruby and bundler
# Install Bundler
ENV CONFIGURE_OPTS --disable-install-doc
RUN rbenv install 2.4.1 && \
echo 'gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri' >> ~/.gemrc && \
rbenv global 2.4.1 && \
rbenv local 2.4.1 && \
gem install bundler

ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

My problem is that when I build the image and start a container

```
docker build -t test .
docker run -it --name test-container test
```

If I run the commands directly in the container shell,
ruby is 2.4.1 (as I'd expect after running `rbenv global 2.4.1`)

```
ruby -v    # 2.4.1p111
which ruby # /root/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

But if I open a new shell and use docker exec,
ruby is 2.3.1, which is the system default

```
docker exec test-container ruby -v    # 2.3.1p112
docker exec test-container which ruby # /usr/bin/ruby
```

---

I think it could have something to do with the bash profile not starting rbenv properly when using `docker exec`. The `env` command seems to have less output when using `docker exec` too, which is why I suspect something to do with .bashrc, .profile, or even /etc/profile not loading somehow.

How can I ensure docker exec produces the same result as running the command directly on the container?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to bash initialization process.
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

In your `Dockerfile`, at lines 12-14 you are patching files, but do not activate any of rbenvs.
Later at your last `RUN` call, you finally ARE activating an rbenv. This starts pointing at that specific version of ruby (I thin this patches `root` files)
At that point you have different global shell initialization files vs. user initialization files.

Difference

- entry point: "non-login" initialization process happens, then the file: `/root/.bashrc` is executed (a.k.a. "sourced"), it points to your cool ruby
- `exec` of `ruby`: ruby executable is located using your default `PATH`. without running `/root/.bash*` files.

To validate all this you can append printouts to your shell's initialization files, and see what gets printed upon 2 cases.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That makes sense, but is there a way I can force `docker exec` to source .bashrc without actually prepending `source ~/.bashrc && ` to every command I want to run? The reason this is an issue is that I have to start the container in detached mode, so I can only use exec to run commands. The only solution I've found so far is to force a symlink to /usr/bin/ruby `ln -nsf  ~/.rbenv/shims/ruby /usr/bin/ruby ` but that could break applications from ubuntu that rely on the system ruby version.

Comment: @con-- I think you can create a wrapper script to do that for you, call it `/arbitrary_exec.sh` and do all the magic in it, executing everything as is at its bottom line: `"${@}"`, invoke by `exec /arbitrary_exec.sh mycmd bla bla bbla`

Comment: or you can put the bashrc in /etc/bashrc - or softlink or hardlink them

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to solve it as follows:
(Side-note: I had not much time to look deep into the topic, so I can not explain in detail why it works, but it worked)

When executing `sudo docker -it exec container /bin/bash` I believe the shell gets started in interactive mode. This mode will source the .bashrc and so on (See link in answer from mvk_il).

But with `sudo docker exec -it container /bin/bash -c '<cmd>'` the bash is executed in a different mode (I think even using " or ' can make kind of a difference).

**My solution:**
Execute the bash specificly in interactive mode and as a login shell. by that, it should behave the same way as if you enter the container and type the command by hand.
`sudo docker exec -it container /bin/bash -ilc '<cmd>'`